# Dielectrics in Capacitors

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance, dielectric

Is dielectric capable of storing charge?

I mean if a dielectric is removed out of a charged capacitor will it still have charges stored into it??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do capacitors in a dielectric have the same charge as without the dielectric](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/319334/)

Answer (score 0):

The charge on the plates remains the same. The voltage goes up. And you had to do work too pull out the dielectric from between the plates, so the stored energy also goes up.

The dielectric loses its polarization. (Unless it was a ferroelectric material.)

Answer (score 0):

> Is dielectric capable of storing charge?

Although dielectrics can be charged (via triboelectricity, for instance), they do not store any net charge when used in a capacitor - they are just polarized.

> I mean if a dielectric is removed out of a charged capacitor will it
>   still have charges stored into it?

No, since it did not store any charge in the first place. It will be just depolarized.